# WFS nearest feature by CQL Filter

Tags: wfs, proximity, cql

At the moment I have a WFS with the following `cql_filter`:

```
'cql_filter: 'dwithin(bag:geometrie, point(lon lat), 100, meters)'
```

The problem is that this filter does not sort the features from closest to farthest.

I would like to know if anybody is either able to sort this list appropriately, or if anybody knows how to get the closest feature in another way.

Answer (score 1):

According to Andrea at http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/find-nearest-features-around-point-without-distance-parameter-td3787318.html:

> There is no standard WFS filter doing that, but we have a WPS process
> offering such functionality. It works without requiring special
> supports from the data access level, as such it's generic and not
> super fast.

What rather works for me is to use a SQL view (in GeoServer) with viewparams to pass in the coordinates like: `&viewparams=lng:12.3;lat:23.4` instead of the `cql_filter`

and then use PostGIS's `<->` operator to order by, selecting the first result ref: https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html

```
select * from bag.geometrie
ORDER BY geom <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT(%lng% %lat%)'::geometry 
limit 1
```